# (JavaFX) Dynamically, columns added. but data was not added

Tags: java, fxml, fxmlloader

https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-dynamic-tableview/issues/1

Please refer above link.
JavaFX(fxml) tables columns are dynamically added. but data doesn't add.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the number of columns in your table differs from the number of columns passed in the data.
The error message is: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4